# A proof of 1/0 = ∞

Tags: limits, exponentiation

I have recently come up with a proof of 1/0 = ∞. Here is the proof:

We will first write 1 and 0 as powers of 10.

1 = 10^0

Since the limit of 10^x as x approaches -∞ is equal to 0, 0 = 10^-∞

Therefore, 1/0 = (10^0)/(10^-∞) = 10^(0-(-∞)) = 10^∞ = ∞

---

Is this proof correct?

Comment: In this context, infinity is not a number, but a shorthand notation for a limit.  So you can't really do math with it, or prove anything about it if you don't use limits.  Take your equation and multiply both sides by $0$ an you get $1=0\cdot\infty$.  Shouldn't the right hand side equal zero since it's zero times something?  I

Comment: All those arithemtic operations in your proof (division, exponentiation, subtraction) are ordinarily defined only for numbers. Since infinity is not a number, your arithmetic operations are invalid, unless you can explain to us how you are defining them.

Comment: What will be 1/? Or what about  $\times $ ? The point is that $\infty$ is just a symbol and on its own (independently) it has no meaning.

Comment: @LeeMosher If you use the extended real number line, ∞ and -∞ are treated like actual numbers.

Comment: You could use the same "proof" to show that $1/0 = - \infty$, since  $0 = (-1) \cdot 0$. *I won't continue the rest of your argument, just like the name of the Dark Lord should not be pronounced.* So it's all nonsense.

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Arithmetic_operations, it has a paragraph that explains why $1/0$ is still undefined even in the extended real number line (which by the way is the only place where you can reasonably perform the kind of operations you've performed here).

Comment: [Obligatory wheel theory reference.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... yes and no. It depends on the context in which you set yourself.

For example, consult the operations with the infinity element of the Riemann Sphere: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere#Arithmetic_operations

(Note that on the Riemann Sphere, also the real projective line, you don't make a difference between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$.)

In simple $\mathbb{R}$, where infinity is not an accepted element, this doesn't work, because you're exiting your base set. It's like trying to prove that $-2$ is a natural number, since $5 - 7 = -2$. However, this is not how $\mathbb{N}$ works: $-$ is not a closed operator in $\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

Who told you that $\frac{1}{0}$ is $\infty$ !!

This expression is simply undefined as division by zero is undefined.

However following is correct

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{1}{x}=\infty$

As you already said in question that

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to -\infty}10^{-x}=0$

then how can you say that $10^{-\infty}=0$. Both the expressions are different.

Comment: You would need to fix the limit to only include the right side: $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

> Since the limit of $10^x$ as $x$ approaches $-∞$ is equal to $0$, $0 = 10^{-∞}$

This is not correct. Infinity is not a number, so you cannot perform operations like exponentiation with it.

Comment: "Infinity is not a number" is nonsense.

Comment: @plop How is it nonsense? Would you like to define $10^{-\infty}$?

Comment: It is nonsense because it is not saying anything. What is a number? Is $\infty$ really not an element of none of the multiple answers that the first question can have? Moreover, having a concept of "number" is useless in mathematics.

Comment: @plop When I use "number" in this context, I'm referring to a quantity which can be manipulated through arithmetical operations.

Comment: Yes, more nonsense. $\infty$ doesn't necessarily lack that property.

Comment: @plop You still have yet to prove me wrong. What is $1+\infty$? What is $10^{-\infty}$?

Comment: You are the one making an affirmative claim. You are the one that has something to prove. I am just saving you the trouble, by telling you that "number" is not a concept in mathematics.

Comment: @plop Did I not just tell you my reasoning? I define a "number" in this context as a quantity that can be manipulated through arithmetical operations. Infinity cannot, so it does not fit this definition and is thus not a number.

Comment: @Kman3 If you use the extended real number line, then you can perform operations on ∞ and -∞.

Comment: @MathGeek Sure, but $\infty$ and $-\infty$ in that case are being _treated like_ numbers, and the results of each operation are constructed with that in mind. With that being said, it is also problematic for $\frac{1}{0}=\infty$ because what is $\frac{2}{0}$? Also infinity? $2\infty$? Then $2\infty=\infty$.

Comment: @Kman3 If 1/0 = ∞, then any number divided by 0 is equal to ∞.

Comment: @MathGeek Which means $\frac{1}{0}=\frac{2}{0}$, leading to the contradiction I stated.

Comment: @Kman3 Yes, but if you cross multiply the two fractions, you get 0=0, which is a true statement.

Comment: @MathGeek But then by your logic you've just done $0 \times \infty$, which is not defined in your extended real number line.

Comment: You've also done $1 \times \frac{0}{0} = 0$, which also defines $\frac{0}{0}=0$ when it is not defined.

Comment: If you cross multiply, you get 1*0 = 2*0, which is equivalent to 0=0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126780/discussion-between-mathgeek-and-kman3).